# Как создать круглую цветную диаграмму с двумя оттенками?

Tags: html, svg, frontend, диаграммы, d3.js

Я пытаюсь сделать круглую цветную диаграмму, которая выглядит, как на рисунке ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу использовать для этого angularJS, SVG и D3.js

Но не знаю, как получить эти закругленные концы, пожалуйста, помогите. Благодарю.

Перевод вопроса: [How to Build this Rounded Two Tone Donut Chart?  @Swapnil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27666584/7394871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Простой ответ: используйте маски.**

Мы используем маску для рисования внутренней части рамки (для одного из оттенков ), и вторую маску, чтобы вырезать отверстие посередине.

Маска отверстия на самом деле не нужна. Вы можете сформировать диаграмму с толстыми линиями.   Но мне было легче рисовать круговые сектора, а затем вырезать отверстие.

Здесь диаграмма находится в форме SVG. Я оставлю конверсию в D3 вам.

```html
<svg version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 800 800" 
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <!-- masks out the area outside and inside the inner bevel region -->
        <mask id="innerbevel">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="235" fill="white"/>
        </mask>
        <!-- cuts hole in centre of graph -->
        <mask id="centrehole">
            <rect x="-100%" y="-100%" width="200%" height="200%" fill="white"/>
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="195" fill="black"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>

    <!-- Graph is drawn centred at (0,0). The transform moves it into middle of SVG. -->
    <!-- The mask forms the hole in the centre. -->
    <g transform="translate(300,300)" mask="url(#centrehole)">
        <!-- outer bevel -->
        <g>
            <!-- light blue segment -->
            <path d="M0 0 0 -275 A 275 275 0 0 1 0 275" fill="#89e4d2"/>
            <!-- red segment -->
            <path d="M0 0 0 275 A 275 275 0 0 1 -275 0" fill="#f394a2"/>
            <!-- blue segment -->
            <path d="M0 0 -275 0 A 275 275 0 0 1 0 -275" fill="#a3a4ff"/>

            <!-- light blue rounded end -->
            <circle cx="0" cy="235" r="40" fill="#89e4d2"/>
            <!-- red rounded end -->
            <circle cx="-235" cy="0" r="40" fill="#f394a2"/>
            <!-- blue rounded end -->
            <circle cx="0" cy="-235" r="40" fill="#a3a4ff"/>
        </g>
        <!-- inner bevel - same as above but with different colours and is masked -->
        <g mask="url(#innerbevel)">
            <!-- light blue segment -->
            <path d="M0 0 0 -275 A 275 275 0 0 1 0 275" fill="#5bc8b7"/>
            <!-- red segment -->
            <path d="M0 0 0 275 A 275 275 0 0 1 -275 0" fill="#ef6974"/>
            <!-- blue segment -->
            <path d="M0 0 -275 0 A 275 275 0 0 1 0 -275" fill="#6b5dff"/>

            <!-- light blue rounded end -->
            <circle cx="0" cy="235" r="40" fill="#5bc8b7"/>
            <!-- red rounded end -->
            <circle cx="-235" cy="0" r="40" fill="#ef6974"/>
            <!-- blue rounded end -->
            <circle cx="0" cy="-235" r="40" fill="#6b5dff"/>
        </g>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [How to Build this Rounded Two Tone Donut Chart? @Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27674166/7394871)